# Deriving divergence in cylindrical coordinates, using covariant derivatives

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, coordinate-systems, vector-fields, covariance

Covariant derivatives are normally used to write equations covariantly in curved spaces. But in an exercise, I need to use covariant derivatives to derive Gauss' law: $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = 4\pi\rho$ in cylindrical coordinates (The main point is to verify that writing the divergence covariantly, makes it the same in all coordinates, so JUST TO BE CLEAR, this is not a relativistic calculation at all, we just try to check that the language works by checking it for 3-vectors).

This does not work, the correct answer is that:

$$\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial E^\phi}{\partial \phi} +\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial (r E^r)}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial E^z}{\partial z}  = 4\pi\rho$$

But I get

$$\frac{\partial E^\phi}{\partial \phi} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial (r E^r)}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial E^z}{\partial z}  = 4\pi\rho$$

Which is off by a factor of $r^{-1}$ on the $\phi$ derivative. My derivation is as follows:

In 3D cartesian coordinates, I can write $\nabla E = E^{\mu}_{\ ,\mu}$ (Here I use index up vectors, to store the components of the E-field)  Where I use the notation $A_{,\mu}=\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^\mu}$. In cartesian coordinates ($x^\mu=(x,y,z)$ ) $g^{00}=g_{00}=g^{11}=g_{11}=g^{22}=g_{22}=1$, so the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\ \nu\eta}=g^{\mu \chi}[g_{\chi \nu,\eta}-g_{\nu\eta,\chi}+g_{\eta\chi,\nu}]/2$ are 0, so the derivatives are equal to the covariant derivative $E^{\mu}_{\ ;\nu}=E^{\mu}_{\ ,\nu}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\ \eta\nu}E^\eta$. (Where $;$ denotes the covariant derivatives). So in cartesian coordinates, Gauss' law becomes:

$$E^{\mu}_{\ ;\mu}=4\pi\rho$$

This is covariant (since the scalar on the right is always covariant), so this must be the same in all systems, including cylindrical coordinates:

In cylindrical coordinates, we have

$$x=r \cos(\phi) ,\quad y=r \sin(\phi), \quad z = z$$

So

$$dx=dr \cos(\phi)-r \sin(\phi) d\phi ,\quad y=dr \sin(\phi)+r \cos(phi)d\phi, \quad dz = dz$$

So:

$$ds^2 = dr^2 (\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)) + r^2 (\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)) d\phi^2+dz^2$$.

Where the cross-terms with $\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)rdrd\phi$ cancels. Since $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$ uf $x^{\mu} = (r,\phi,z)$, I believe that this implies:

$$g_{00}=1,\quad g_{11}=r^2, \quad g_{22}=1$$

The requirement that $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\nu\eta}=\delta^{\mu}_{\eta}$ clearly $g^{11}=1/r^2$, while $g^{00}=g^{22}=1$. (With everything else $0$)

Now writing out:

$$E^{\mu}_{\ ;\mu} = E^{\nu}_{\ ,\mu}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\ \eta\mu}E^\eta $$

Gives:

$$E^{0}_{\ ;0} = E^{0}_{\ ,0} + \Gamma^{0}_{\ \eta0}E^{\eta}=E^{0}_{\ ,0}=\frac{\partial E^r}{\partial r}$$

Since $\Gamma^{0}_{\ \eta0}$ contain either terms with  $\eta\neq 0$ where  $g_{\eta 0,0}= \partial 0/\partial r=0$ and terms with $g_{00,\eta}=0$ since $g_{00}=1$ is constant. The same goes for:

$$E^{2}_{\ ;2} = E^{2}_{\ ,2} = \frac{\partial E^z}{\partial z} $$

Now for the $\phi$ coordinate, the only non-zero Christoffel symbol is:

$$\Gamma^{1}_{\ 01} = g^{1 \chi}[g_{\chi 0,1}-g_{01,\chi}+g_{1\chi,0}]/2=g^{11}g_{11,0}/2 = \frac{1}{2r^2} \frac{\partial r^2}{\partial r}=\frac{1}{r}$$

Then I believe:

$$E^{1}_{\ ;1} = E^{1}_{\ ,1}+\Gamma^{1}_{\ 01}E^{0}=\frac{\partial  E^{\phi}}{\partial \phi}+\frac{E^r}{r}$$

This is almost correct:

$$E^\mu_{\ ;\mu}=E^{0}_{\ ;0}+E^{1}_{\ ;1}+E^{2}_{\ ;2}= \frac{\partial E^{\phi}}{\partial \phi}+\frac{E^r}{r} + \frac{\partial E^r}{\partial r} +  \frac{\partial E^z}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial E^{\phi}}{\partial \phi} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r E^r}{\partial r} +  \frac{\partial E^z}{\partial z}$$

Where I used the fact that $\partial (r E^r)/\partial r= r \partial (E^r)/\partial r+E^r$, this is the only result I am able to get, and it is correct, except for the fact that the $\phi$ component of the field is missing a factor of $1/r$. Since $g_{11}=r^2$, shifting the indices up or down can not give the missing $1/r$ factor.

I am aware that cylindrical coordinates normally has this $1/r$ factor, but the whole point of using covariant derivatives is that the equations should work in any systems as is.

Comment: I don’t want to go through all your Gamma calculations, because that’s likely where you messed up. Google the Voss-Weyl formula, which tells you $\text{div}(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(\sqrt{|g|}X^i\right)$. Here, $\sqrt{|g|}=\sqrt{1\cdot r^2\cdot 1}=r$.

Comment: It’s unconventional to use Greek indices for spatial indices, and it’s unconventional to number spatial indices 0,1,2.

Comment: You just made a mistake in the angular component. While in physics you use $e_\phi$, the basis vector is $\partial_\phi=re_\phi$ and the formula for covariant derivatives is in the latter basis $\partial_i$. You'd get the same issue in spherical coordinates.

Comment: And btw to compute the Christoffel symbol it’s faster to use the euler-lagrange equations for geodesics since it will directly give you the non zero terms.